# Python Count not resetting?

Tags: python, count, increment

I'm trying to insert an increment after the occurance of ~||~ in my .txt. I have this working, however I want to split it up, so after each semicolon, it starts back over at 1.

So Far I have the following, which does everything except split up at semicolons.

```
inputfile = "output2.txt"    
outputfile = "/output3.txt"  
f = open(inputfile, "r")  
words = f.read().split('~||~')  
f.close()  
count = 1   
for i in range(len(words)):  
      if ';' in words [i]:  
        count = 1  
    words[i] += "~||~" + str(count)  
    count = count + 1  
f2 = open(outputfile, "w")  
f2.write("".join(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resetting the counter the way you are now, you could do the initial split on `;`, and then split the substrings on `~||~`. You'd have to store your words another way, since you're no longer doing `words = f.read().split('~||~')`, but it's safer to make an entirely new list anyway.

```
inputfile = "output2.txt"    
outputfile = "/output3.txt"  
all_words = []
f = open(inputfile, "r")  
lines = f.read().split(';')
f.close()

for line in lines:
  count = 1
  words = line.split('~||~')
  for word in words:
    all_words.append(word + "~||~" + str(count))
    count += 1

f2 = open(outputfile, "w")  
f2.write("".join(all_words))
```

See if this works for you. You also may want to put some strategically-placed newlines in there, to make the output more readable.

Comment: I just tried this..it looks like it removed all of my ~||~ entirely..what did I do wrong?

Comment: @user3754031 can you update your question with a sample of what the input and output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Why not first split the file based on the semicolon, then in each segment count the occurences of '~||~'.

```
import re

count = 0

with open(inputfile) as f:
    semicolon_separated_chunks = f.read().split(';')
    count = len(re.findall('~||~', semicolon_separated_chunks))

# if file text is 'hello there ~||~ what is that; what ~||~ do you ~|| mean; nevermind ~||~'
# then count = 4
```

Comment: His code suggests that he needs a running count appended to the output, though I'm not too sure why that is.

Comment: Hard to explain..loading txt file into something else. needs to be broken up in this way.